# Remote desktop application using UDP sockets in Java

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, live-streaming

I'm developing a sort of remote desktop application, where the Android client is able to show the screen of the desktop (and control it as well).

The problem is streaming the video. My solution was to capture screenshots using the Java Robot class, resized them according to the target device resolution and send them over DatagramPackets to the android client. Then I found out that raw Images were to big to be send over a single UDP packet (because it was over 62KB) and so it would give me one of these.

```
IOException: Message too long
```

So I compressed the images to JPEG with a quality setting of 0.25 until I was finally able get the size of the frames reasonably below 62KB. But even still the image sizes sometimes gets too large and cause the frame to be not sent. The code for this at present is:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(
                    new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            BufferedImage resizedSS = Scalr.resize(screenshot,
                    Scalr.Method.BALANCED, screenSizeX, screenSizeY);
            byte[] imageBuff = compressToJPEG(resizedSS, 0.25f);

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(imageBuff, imageBuff.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "LiveScreenSender.run: error while sending screenshot");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for JPEG compression (note: this is a modified version of code I found somewhere on SO, and don't fully understand how it works)

```java
private static byte[] compressToJPEG(BufferedImage image, float quality) throws IOException {
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    // compress to a given quality
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

    ios.close();
    writer.dispose();

    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

The client (Android) part also being fairly similar

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            socket.receive(dataBuffPacket);
            if (dataBuffPacket.getLength() == 0) break;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataBuffPacket.getData(), 0, dataBuffPacket.getLength());
            onFrameReceive(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if UDP packet lengths are limited, what is the conventional way of live video streaming using UDP. I need some suggestions for which direction to go to, for solving this. Any library recommendations would be most appreciated. As far as I've seen on the internet most questions and blogs pertain to streaming content stored on a server, not video generated in real time frame by frame.

My knowledge regarding networking and A/V playback is fairly limited so I would appreciate good tutorials or links as to where I might be able to learn these.

Comment: `what is the conventional way of live video streaming using UDP. ` I dont know. You are not streaming live video but sending a jpg now and then. After requiring the screendump i would not resize it to the dimensions of the receiving device. Leave it as it is. Compressing to jpg is a good idea. But let the client determine the compressquality. Mostly 25 or even 15 will be ok but now and then the client wants to see all details. Then sending the jpg. If one udp packet does not suffice then use more. At receiving side concatenate the packets until the jpg is complete.

Comment: But isn't there a chance that all UDP packets don't reach the destination? That's why I wanted to put the entire frame into a single packet, so if I loose packets it will drop entire frames. But if I divide up the frame how would I handle the missing packets in a single frame?

Comment: If a jpg uses three udp packets and only two arrive then drop the whole jpg. I wonder why you choosed udp. Use tcp then you would not have these problems.

Comment: Maybe because udp is faster than tcp and OP doesnt need ack every time a packet is received

Comment: For now I am implementing it using TCP. Will get back to trying to make my UDP implementation work.

Comment: Gj. I wanted to make similar implementation but dropped when I found out video streaming can only be done by rooted devices. I thought of sending multiple screenshots but didn't implement it because it is heavy on disk usage